# import lift mapper caught an error missing jar file

Tags: lift

hi im creating a lift scala application

this is my problem

when i  **import net.liftweb.mapper._ package**  the compiler gives me error...

i tried to add **lift-mapper_2.9.1-2.4-M4.jar** jar file to build path ,but the error exists..!

the compiler shows..

```
bad symbolic reference. A signature in package.class refers to term db in package net.liftweb which is not available. It may be completely missing from 
 the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling package.class.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the mapper via `SBT` or `maven` configuration?

Anyway, Scala-2.9.1 and Lift 2.4-M4 are very-very out of date. Better use something like that for a good start: https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/

It works out of the box, and you'll only have to add 1 line to add the `mapper` support for it. (After that, all dependencies would be downloaded and added to the project automatically, by `SBT`.)